# uchar to ushort in python

Tags: python, type-conversion

My title might seem strange since there are no such things as uchar and ushort in Python so let me explain :
I get a list of 8 bits data from a bulk transfer but I need these in 16 bits. Hence I do this :

```
frame = dev.read(0x82, packetLength, interface, timeout) # bulk transfer
if len(frame) == packetLength
    for i in range(0, packetLength, 2):
        newFrame.append(frame[i+1]*256 + frame[i])
```

So yes it works but it is extremely slow and I need to run it on a Raspberry Pi...

Does anyone of you know a better way to do the same thing?

Comment: maybe `struct`? http://stackoverflow.com/a/10940583/610569

Comment: Precisely, what data structure does `dev.read()` return?

Comment: Actually, that's pretty fast. How fast do you need?

Comment: Maybe shifting and masking is more efficient than multiplying by 256. something like: y = (x << 8) & 0xFF00

Answer (score 2):

Using `struct`, the solution would be:

```
import struct

frame = dev.read( ... )

fmt = "<%dH" % (len(frame) / 2)
newFrame = struct.unpack(fmt, frame)
```

Explanation of `fmt` string:

- `<` - Data is in little-endian format
- `%d` - The size of your array (it modifies the following format specifier)
- `H` - *Format specifier* Interpret the data as ushorts